# Selenium c# , Xpath is not recognizing

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

i have element but the xpath is not working 
receiving unable to find element with xpath ....

var newnumber = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='1496943330773-0-uiGrid-0006-cell']/div"));

please help me with this?

Comment: It's obvious that the `id` might be dynamic.Go with **contains** `//div[contains(@id,'uiGrid-0006-cell')]` or something

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To handle a dynamic ID, they easiest thing is to remove it.

How to do so in Chrome:

1. Right-click the element and select "Inspect"
2. Double-click the element's id="..." attribute to edit it
3. Delete the attribute and save the changes (by clicking on another element)
4. Right-click the element and select "Copy" -> "Copy Xpath"

Comment: Creating an XPath by using Copy XPath is rarely a good idea. What you typically end up with is a long, fragile reference. It would be better to learn to hand craft the XPath or better yet, use CSS selectors in most cases since they are faster and better supported.

Comment: I agree and use CSS Selector in my tests almost exclusively. I focused on XPath as that's what the post was tagged with.